# Способы использовать JavaScript в Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

это файл по умолчанию в проекте Blazor Assembly, который используется ***как-то***  пытаюсь следовать их примеру

```
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
```

...добавила файл js рядом с файлом в проекте готового решения blazor, теперь пытаюсь указать путь и возможно ещё что-то надо где-то прописать, чтоб файл использовался

```
<script>ТУТ ЧТО ПРОПИСАТЬ ('MOYFAYL.js');</script> или так <script src="dragtable.js"></script>
```

как понимать **navigator.serviceWorker.register**

моя ошибка на выходе

```
MOYFAYL.js:403 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at MOYFAYL.js:403:4
```

*jQuery is not defined* а где его нужно defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start().then(function () {
        var customScript = document.createElement('script');
        customScript.setAttribute('src', 'test.js');
        document.head.appendChild(customScript);
    });
</script>
```

в файл index.html в `<body>` я добавляю `Blazor.start().then(function ()` в скрипт и атрибут `autostart="false"`

в папку `wwwroot` добавляю мой файл джаваскрипт `test.js`

и затем в `.razor-е` использую

```
<button onclick="testFunc()">change color</button> 
<div class="block">Red color</div>
<!--testFunc меняет цвет в файле test.js-->
```

- в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) говорится, что лучше не использовать js в assembly Blazor, но если есть необходимость, то предлагают этот вариант. ***Проверила, работает***

Answer (score 1):

```
@code {
[Inject]
protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var jQuery = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("$", ".defaultTable"); //класс таблицы

        await jQuery.InvokeVoidAsync("dragtable"); //функция в .js
    }
}
```

вот как можно повесить действие на класс в .razor

Answer (score 0):

предложу еще способ, данный способ в Блазор Сервер использую

в Import добавляю зависимость Js

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
```

некий event используемый у тега на странице разор

```
public async Task OpenHandler()
{
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JSMethod");
}
```

и в _Layout.cshtml добавляю script

```
 <script>
     function JSMethod() {
        do somethink....
     }
 </script>
```

- такой метод можно использовать для таких задач, как например показать тултип те что то визуальное